# Exception while dropping database in JavaFX

Tags: mysql, database, exception, jdbc

```
 private void delete() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delete?"
                    + "user=root&password=virus");
    statement = connect.createStatement();

    preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("DROP DATABASE delete");
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE delete");
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

This is my code to delete a database in javafx. But when i ran this code it gives me an exception. Is details are -

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at deleteaccount.DeleteAccount.delete(DeleteAccount.java:106)
at deleteaccount.DeleteAccount.access$000(DeleteAccount.java:26)
at deleteaccount.DeleteAccount$1.handle(DeleteAccount.java:86)
at deleteaccount.DeleteAccount$1.handle(DeleteAccount.java:82)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
```

Why this exception occur ? How can I solve it ?

Comment: Show us the query that fails and a relevant fragment of code. In this listing is no code that executes "delete" query so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk What do you mean ? Which relevant fragment of code should I post ?

Comment: Is your database named "delete"? Why are you connecting to `localhost:3306/delete`?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Yes that is my database name.

Comment: And you know that `DELETE` is a reserved word in SQL? Change database name to any safe name, eg. `my_delete` or `localdb` (anything outside SQL keywords), change connection code and tell what happened.